# Graphical Workflow Editor plugin to Eclipse/IntelliJ/Webapp

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

I'm considering developing a multi-platform graphical workflow editor as a plugin for Eclipse and/or IntelliJ. The editor would work in a way similar to tools such as Visio/OmniGraffle/Activiti Designer/FuseIDE. It would allow the developers to drag and drop components from a toolbox, connect them using the mouse (or would-be-cool touch), and even run simulation of the workflow (highlighting component by component and show their corresponding value).

Some more important features include:

1- It should enable the developers to go back and forth between their code (Java/Scala) and the workflow editor.

2- It should be able to connect to a web application which displays the model on a browser (if possible in real-time).

Basically, the final product would look something like that depicted in the 2 pictures below.

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [fusesource.com](http://fusesource.com/images/fuse-ide-21.png))</sub>

I did some research and found out that Eclipse supported the development of workflow-oriented plugins with the [Graphical Modeling Framework](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial#Get_started). But I can't seem to find any similar support for IntelliJ. Our team internally uses IntelliJ and I believe that it provides a more intuitive and developer-friendly experience than Eclipse.

Can you provide me a few hints on how to start building my plugin? How is IntelliJ's support for such interactive editor, compared to Eclipse? Or would you suggest a third approach (web-based IDE, tool...)? A few references would be more than enough. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: 3 years later, I am working on something similar and would like to know what you went with. It will be great if you can share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I found this plugin for IntelliJ. It works for Activiti framework. 
This is the description: Activiti Designer plugin for Intellij Idea

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7429

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but I've created an IntelliJ plugin for the **Flowable BPMN engine** that closely matches your requirement - navigation between BPMN and code.

I think you can use sources of my plugin to understand how to build your own.

Here is the plugin link:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14318-flowable-bpmn-visualizer

And here are the sources:
https://github.com/valb3r/flowable-bpmn-intellij-plugin

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add some additional information as to how this could be implemented to solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks, I've added short clarification.
Well, my plugin is open-sourced and provides something very similar to what is described in the question. The author can take a look at the implementation of the thing he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out PolyBPMN visualiser Intellij IDEA plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21361-polybpmn-visualizer

It supports files with extension *.bpmn, *.bpmn.xml *.bpmn20.

See also polybpmn.com